# Spring data elasticsearch query products with multiple fields

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

ES newbie here, sorry for the dumb question.

I have been trying to create a elasticsearch query for a `products` index. I'm able to query it, but it never returns as I expect.

I'm probably using the query builder in a wrong way, have tried all sorts of queries builders and never got to make it work as I expected.

My **Product** class (simpler for the sake of the question):

```
public class Product {

    private String sku;

    private Boolean soldOut;

    private Boolean freeShipping;

    private Store store;

    private Category category;

    private Set<ProductUrl> urls;

    private Set<ProductName> names;

}
```

**Category** nas `name` and `id` which I use for aggregations

The boolean field are used for filters.

**ProductName** and **ProductUrl** both have a `String locale` and `String name` or `String url` accordingly

I am currently building my query with the following logic

```
private SearchQuery buildSearchQuery(String searchTerm, List<Long> categories, Pageable pageable) {
    NativeSearchQueryBuilder builder = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder();
    if (searchTerm != null) {
        builder.withQuery(
                new MultiMatchQueryBuilder(searchTerm, "names.name", "urls.url", "descriptions.description", "sku")
                        .operator(Operator.AND)
                        .type(MultiMatchQueryBuilder.Type.MOST_FIELDS)
        );
    }
    builder.withPageable(pageable);
    return builder.build();
}
```

The problem is that lots of products are not being matched, for example:

query "andro" does not return "android" products.

What am I missing? Is this way of building the query right?

**UPDATE**
Adding the `names` part of my product mapping:

```
    {
    "mappings": {
        "product": {
            "properties": {
                "names": {
                    "properties": {
                        "id": {
                            "type": "long"
                        },
                        "name": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "locale": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Generally if andro is not returning android and similar problems, your mapping is incorrect for what you are trying to achieve, for example your analyzers might be off. Could you post your mapping?

Comment: I have updated the question with the names mapping. It's the default mapping actually, I index the data with spring-data-elasticsearch no mapping, ES created it on the fly....guess that must be it.

Comment: Like Daniel mentions, you cannot find a partial match if you use standard mapping. You could use a fuzzy query or add something like a prefix ngram analyser.

Comment: thanks, I'll play around with the mappings and try to understand this. Even though ES is fairly simple to configure/understand I haven't dealt with lots of text indexing stuff so I fell lost sometimes.